# Passing parameters or variable using location()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reload a page using location() in JavaScript and would also like to pass a variable value. below step didn't work for me. Let me know the correct procedure.

```
 location='success.jsp'+<%=ID%>;
```

Comment: `location='success.jsp?'+<%=ID%>;` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do something like:

```
window.location='success.jsp?VARIABLE_NAME='+<%=ID%>;
```